# Are there any alternative ways for find_each method?

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-2

I have been using Rails 2.3.5.
I would like to use find_each method, but it is not in the version.

Are there any alternative ways to use find_each method for Active Record?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using find_in_batches:

```
Model.find_in_batches(:batch_size => 1000)  do |records|
    records.each { |record| <your logic here> }
end
```

Comment: I appreciate for your telling it to me. I could do what I wanted.